# How to format java formatted field that it formats it self when user types?

Tags: java, format, field

I want a user to type in a date in formatted field of format yyyy-MM-dd , but i dont want my user to need to type "-" , so i want him to type 20180303 and the feld automatically adds the "-". And to check if the date is valid.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing and validation:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20180303",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
```

If date is incorrect or can not be parsed this will throw a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`